# Snowflake How to remove double quotes from the unloaded file from snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I unload the data from snowflake through the copy command the Varchar255 records from the snowflake, it adds double quote to separate each records. How would I be able to unload records without double quotes

Comment: Please add some sample code and results to help us debug

Comment: So the column value for Varchar255 is Manchester United 007 it is stored without double quotes when I do: copy into \@table from table file_format=(my_file_format) max_size=320000000 it adds the double quotes around the record as “Manchester United 007”, I need those records without double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can set FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY parameter to '"' to removed double quotes:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

> FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY : Character used to enclose strings.
> Value can be NONE, single quote character ('), or double quote
> character ("). To use the single quote character, use the octal or hex
> representation (0x27) or the double single-quoted escape ('').

Answer (score 0):

As Gokhan said, use FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY. But beware of an important special use case here:

If your field separator is comma, and your string value is let's say "Manchester United, 007" - instead of "Manchester United 007" (with no comma inside!) - your value will still be exported with quotes in the unloaded file.

Otherwise "Manchester United" would be considered a field value, and "007" another field value.